# Converting a column from NOT NULL to NULL. What's going on under the hood?

Tags: sql-server

We have a table with 2.3B rows in it. We'd like to change a column from NOT NULL to NULL. The column is contained in one index (not the clustered or PK index). The data type isn't changing (it's an INT). Just the nullability. The statement is as follows:

```
Alter Table dbo.Workflow Alter Column LineId Int NULL
```

The operation takes in excess of 10 before we stop it (we haven't even let it run to completion yet because it's a blocking operation and was taking too long). We'll probably copy the table to a dev server a test how long it actually takes. But, I'm curious if anyone knows what SQL Server is doing under the hood when converting from NOT NULL to NULL? Also, will affected indexes need to get rebuilt? The query plan generated doesn't indicate what's happening.

SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: sounds like more of a dba.stackexchange.com kinda question.

Comment: ...which means wait for the question to be migrated, please, don't go post an identical question there. Too late for this time, [obviously](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97738/sql-server-changing-a-column-from-not-null-to-null-whats-going-on-under-the), but please consider this next time.

Answer (score 0):

How long did you let it run before you canceled it? 2.3 Billion is a big number, it will take time.

The reason you experienced some blocking is because SQL Server will obtain Schema Lock on the `WHOLE TABLE` when updating table definition.

The schema lock, locks down the whole table, even dirty reads are blocked too.

I would suggest, execute the Alter table statement in least busy time and be patient, like I said before 2 billion is a big number and it will take time.

**Schema Locks**

> The Database Engine uses schema modification (Sch-M) locks during a
>   table data definition language (DDL) operation, such as adding a
>   column or dropping a table. During the time that it is held, the Sch-M
>   lock prevents concurrent access to the table. This means the Sch-M
>   lock blocks all outside operations until the lock is released.
>
> Some data manipulation language (DML) operations, such as table
>   truncation, use Sch-M locks to prevent access to affected tables by
>   concurrent operations.

Source [`Lock Modes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't tell me what SQL Server is actually doing under the hood to convert the column to nullable.

Comment: It obtains a `SCHEMA LOCK` on the table to do the table Definition update. What other information are you looking for?